# how to start Quartz Scheduler automatically in Java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz Scheduler 2.2.1 in a webapp which is built on Tomcat webserver. I use a servlet to start Quartz . However, if the system reboots, I also have to restart Quartz manually by sending request to that servlet. Therefore, the problem is how to start Quartz automatically !

One more thing that is I want to use Quartz to perform a task at 00:00:00 everyday, so what is the best design for the trigger in this case ?

Comment: Are you running on a Linux machine? Can you consider writing a S99 script in your rcN.d ?

Comment: You're in a webapp => use web.xml. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975704/integration-of-tomcat-and-quartz-scheduler-on-startup

Answer (score 1):

You should use a custom ServletContextListener and configure it in your web.xml for automatically starting your cron job.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654

If not satisfied by the Oracle link, do a little Google and you will get plenty of examples

To start a cron job every day at 12:00 am the below cron pattern should work:

```
0 0 0 * * ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a ServletContextListener and implement a contextInitialized() method  that starts quartz. This listener gets triggered if the tomcat is restarted or your servlet is redeployed