# Quartz job at startup - Context Listener Addition

Tags: tomcat, startup, jobs, schedule

My goal is to get a Quartz job scheduled at the time the Tomcat server starts up.  I created a test class (in Java) that sets up the scheduling the way that I need, as well as a class that it would run when it triggers (again, Java).

I'm following the "option 2" of this thread, as well as its answer from the Quartz site:

[Integration of tomcat and Quartz scheduler on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975704/integration-of-tomcat-and-quartz-scheduler-on-startup)

It says I need to:
"....start the scheduler inside the contextInitialized method and shutdown the scheduler inside contextDestroyed method"

Where are those two methods?  I'm assuming I would put some kind of reference to the "scheduling class" I made above, which connects to the "job class".

Or am I off base, and should be doing this through some other means?  I found this link, but I think I would run into the sample problem.

[Quartz run job on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943473/quartz-run-job-on-startup)

Tomcat 7
Quartz 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes....I should have done this in XML.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/example-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-quartz/